# Progress bar while downloading RSS feed

Tags: android, rss, progress-bar

I'm working on a program to parse a specific RSS fees and I'm trying to display a progress bar while the feed is downloaded and parsed.  I've looked through the android developer tutorials and have noticed that some people use async task and others us handlers.  I've tried many of the examples, but none of them work properly.  I either get a "force close", or the progress bar won't display at all.

Any suggestions on the best way to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AsyncTask provides an easier approach if you want to do some background work in a separate thread, and update the UI based on the status of that operation.

Comment: Thanks, I found a couple of good tutorials [here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/07/read-rss-in-background-using-asynctask.html) and [here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/07/asynctask-perform-background-operations.html).